# How can I lower the CPU usage on MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, central-processing-unit

We are running a Wowonder-based social site for a little community and as soon as we hit 100 users online, our site becomes extremely slow due to high CPU usage. The script itself should be fine because none of the other customers have issues with this so I believe something on our side is doomed. This is our glances report with a hundred users online: 
[glances report.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QowGq.png)
As you can see, our CPU usage is way too high, even after setting cache policies. We tried running without query_cache but the result was the same.

`[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 26
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_read_io_threads = 16
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 26G
innodb_io_capacity=300
innodb_log_file_size=3G
performance_schema=ON
table_definition_cache=10000
join_buffer_size=256M
skip-name-resolve
key_buffer_size     = 512M
max_allowed_packet  = 512M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 10
myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 1000
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 256K
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
query_cache_size = 50M`

As said before, the code itself should be fine because it runs well on other instances but not on this one. Any ideas would be highly appreciated. Let me know if I can assist somehow, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Show us a query or two, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE for the table(s) involved.  ("You can't tune you way out of a CPU problem")

Comment: enable slow query logs with long_query_time=0 and collect slow queries during peak hours when you notice high CPU usage for about 15-30mins (or more?) and parse it with pt-query-digest to understand which queries are slow and need tuning

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, high CPU usage means slow (poorly indexed or poorly designed) queries. Configuration generally has a much smaller impact, and bad configuration will typically make your CPU usage lower and queries slower.

Having said that, some parts of your configuration are egregiously poor:

```
join_buffer_size=256M
```

This is quite likely increasing your CPU usage *and* crippling your performance. Comment it out, leave it on default value.

You almost certainly don't need to touch these away from defaults, so consider commenting them out:

```
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 10
```

These usually do more harm than good:

```
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 256K
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
query_cache_size = 50M
```

Consider replacing with:

```
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is to complement @Gordan Bobic

Check which queries are slow:

```
mysql -e "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE COMMAND<>'Sleep' and TIME > 5"
```

For each query that is slow run an [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) on the query. You can install Percona Tools and run [pt-visual-explain](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-visual-explain.html) to have a better representation of the `EXPLAIN` statement.

If you are using InnoDB engine, you can see what it is doing with:

```
mysql -e "show engine innodb status \G"
```

Other details can be found in [MySQL Performance Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema.html) which includes a [profiler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html) too. [Here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/04/16/profiling-mysql-queries-from-performance-schema/) is a Percona article about the profiler.

If you want to have a better picture of the CPU utilization, you can use `perf` + [FlameGraphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html).

Comment: Nice tool. However MySQL has a performance schema and an integrated profiler.

Comment: @liaf You may also wish to consider JetProfiler.com website that has free Trial software (no Expiration Date) to find Top Queries and Top Tables to target areas to consider. Built in EXPLAIN is conveniently available. Set polling interval to 10 Seconds to minimize on a busy server.